# Xcode WebView; Open hyperlink external if specific get parameter in URL

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, hyperlink, external

I made an iOS app with Xcode an Swift. All hyperlinks are opened in the apps own WebView. But I want to be able to open specific hyperlinks external, means in Safari browser.

I want to open all hyperlinks containing `target=external` as get parameter like this `www.example.com/?target=external` in Safari browser.

Cause I'm not very experienced I don't know how to start.

Can anybody give me a hint, a sample or a link? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the webview delegate methods, [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) or [UIwebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below code to check 
if (url.query == target=external)
{// open in safari
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}else{
//open in web view in app
}

// Note if you are exepecting more than 1 parameter in url you can use componentSeperatedbyString method 

var paramArry = url.query.componentsSeparatedByString("&")
if (paramArry[0] == target=external)
{// open in safari
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}else{
//open in web view in app
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Isn't is easier to use the following if more than one parameter? Code: `if url.query!.rangeOfString("target=external") != nil {}`

Comment: yes you can use it as well, it you don't need other parameters.

Comment: Okay, which later code do you mean? Mine or yours?

Comment: You can use if url.query?.rangeOfString("target=external") != nil {}  if you use "!" it will crash if there is no query parameter, so use "?"

Comment: Okay, you're right `!` really crashed. I changed it to `?`.

Comment: Unfortunately I need more help. I currently have the code: https://codeshare.io/adwyMD. But that only have affect on the first URL, the main URL, but I should (only) work for the hyperlinks in this WebView. What to do?

Comment: Do you mean to open the hyperlinks from the web view? if so, do you want to open it to safari?

Comment: I mean: I'm loading a URL in the WebView in my app. Almost all hyperlinks should get opened in the WebView. But hyperlinks containing `target=external` should get opened in Safari. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes I got it from where you are getting those url from server or they are present in webview?

Comment: The URL's are in an HTML file that gets loaded from my server. It's like you have `www.example.com` as your main URL that gets loaded on first start and then click the `More information...` hyperlink. Imagine the `More information...` hyperlink is: `www.example.com/more_information.php?target=external`.